# Add a line "<IP address of host> <FQDN of host> in /etc/hosts using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a hosts file:

```
[cluster_be1]
10.10.10.10 be1_dns=c-be1.a.b.c.d
```

I want to be able to populate /etc/hosts ( append at the top )

10.10.10.10 c-be1.a.b.c.d

I tried:

```
- name:  build hosts file
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts regexp='.*{{ item }}$' line="{{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]].be1_ip }}"  state=present
    when: "{{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]] }}" is defined
    with_items: play_hosts
```

but getting Error:

```
The error appears to have been in '/home/ec2-user/ANSIBLE/clusterOps/roles/cluster-be1/defaults/main.yml': line 36, column 59, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts regexp='.*{{ item }}$' line="{{ hostvars[groups['chef_be1_cluster'][0]].be1_ip }}"  state=present
    when: "{{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]] }}" is defined
                                                          ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Answer ( with mhutter's help )

```
- name:  build hosts file
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts regexp={{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]].be1_ip }} line="{{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]].be1_ip }} {{ hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]].be1_dns }}"  state=present
    when: hostvars[groups['cluster_be1'][0]] is defined
    with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
```

file "hosts":

```
[cluster_be1]
10.10.10.10 be1_dns=chef-be1-tnp.a.b.c.d be1_ip=10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is a bit inconsisten with when you have to use jinja syntax and when not. I think the correct markup should be:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/hosts
    line: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }} {{ hostvars[item].be1_dns }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ play_hosts }}"
```

References:

- ["lineinfile" module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-module)
- ["when" statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement)
- ["with_items"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-list)

Comment: this works but appends the IP address. Is'nt the regex suppose to take care of the condition that if the IP address is already there do not append?

Comment: Haven't looked at that part exactly, but how it works is: 1) Look for `regexp` 2) if it matches, replace whole line by `line` (and nothing else). So what you want is to simply have one hosts-entry for each host in your inventory? Also note that `when` is evaluatet for the WHOLE task, and NOT for each iteration of the loop

Comment: is there a way to do the inverse. i.e. don't replace the line if present. and for regex, can we pass regexp={{ hostvars[groups['chef_be1_cluster'][0]].be1_ip }}

Comment: @kamal I have updated the answer to include the `lineinfile` part as well. The task now does what you described in your question